# Linked list traversing in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

In the `main` function, I make a node with `n` = 50 and `next` = `NULL`. When I `add` a 10 to the linked list, although it has been added, it does not show up when traversing. The reason why that happens is because the `start` pointer that points to the node with 50 is not updated to point to the new node with 10 when add function is called. (line 28 to line 34).

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void traverse(node* start)
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("%i\n",start->n);
        start = start->next;
        if(start == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void add(int num, node* start)
{
    node* previous = NULL;
    node* current = start;
    if(num<current->n)
    {
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //The problem is inside this if block.
        node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->next = current;
        current = tmp;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    }
    else
    {
        while(true)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
            if(current == NULL)
            {
                node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
                tmp->n = num;
                tmp->next = NULL;
                previous->next = tmp;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(current->n > num)
                {
                    node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
                    tmp->n = num;
                    tmp->next = current;
                    previous->next = tmp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    node* start = malloc(sizeof(node));
    start->n = 50;
    start->next = NULL;
    add(10,start);
    traverse(start);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your functions should be able to properly manage an *empty* list (i.e. NULL head pointer). The crutch of loading a lead-in sentinel noad `start` in `main()` is brittle-at-best, and the resulting functions depend on it (ex: `traverse` will invoke UB if passed a NULL pointer). And your `add()` is about 85% longer than it needs to be.

Comment: @WhozCraig Do i need  `current` and `previous` in `add()`? How can I shorten `add()`?

Comment: Nope. You can do this with one temp pointer  and one pointer-to-pointer (which you'll be passing as a param). [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/OwzYFk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass start as pointer to pointer in the `add` function so that you can modify it exactly in the place you have indicated. Declaration should look something like `void add(int num, node** start)`.

Also you should take care to free the memory allocated for the list before the end of the program.